Стоит ли писать в таком стиле на C?
Стоит ли писать в таком стиле, например хранить ссылки на функции внутри структуры связанной с этими функциями? Просто мне кажется, что это

Тратит много памяти на одну структуру
Немного не про C

typedef struct Relation{
    char* name;     // name of relation
    Node* parent;   // parent   structure
    Node* child;    // children structure
        
    // film1<----- (relation) -----/ tom  \----- (relation) ----> England
    //(child)    name:Acted_IN    |(parent)|    name:Live_IN       (child)

    //void (*create  )(char* name, Node* parent, Node* child); 
    void (*destruct)(Relation* rel); 

} Relation;


typedef struct Data{
    uint8_t type;
    void*   info;

    void (*destruct)(Data* data);
} Data;

typedef struct Node{
    Data*      data;      //         
    Relation** relations; // 
    size_t     rsize;     // relations size      
    
    //Node* (*construct     )(Data* data, Relation* rel);
    void  (*destruct      )(Node* node);
    void  (*add_relation  )(Node* node, Relation* rel);
    void  (*del_relation  )(Node* node, Relation* rel);

} Node;


Пасть :) в любом случае не стоит. По сути — если функции, указатели на которые хранятся в структуре, разные для разных объектов — то это даже логично. Если же одинаковые — то, конечно, можно и так писать, но зачем?!

Для экономии памяти можно внутри структуры хранить только один указатель, на экземпляр структуры (vtable), в котором будут указатели на функции. В результате у вас получатся виртуальные функции, как в С++ - только там эти таблицы за вас будет генерировать компилятор.

Это как раз про C: извратиться и написать через одно место.

просто передавай структуру параметром в метод.

Если задача удобно решается через полиморфизм, это абсолютно нормальный способ.

Для случая, когда каждый тип данных нужно обрабатывать своей функцией @user7860670 дал хороший совет. Если же задача (экзотичная, конечно) состоит в том, что для обработки каждого экземпляра может потребоваться своя функция, то придется хранить ее в этом экземпляре (как у вас).
